# In TypeScript, can I specify the type of object fields while still getting the literal key types inferred?

Tags: typescript, enums, type-inference, singleton-type

What I'm trying to do is to define some kind of "rich enumeration", where each enum key is linked to some data whose type I want to specify.

E.g., something like this:

```js
const Seasons = {
    winter: { temperature: 5, startMonth: "December" },
    spring: { temperature: 20, startMonth: "March" },
    summer: { temperature: 30, startMonth: "June" },
    fall: { temperature: 15, startMonth: "September" },
} as const
```

This declaration is nice and lets me do things like:

```js
type Season = keyof typeof Seasons // "winter" | "spring" | "summer" | "fall"
```

and even a type guard like

```js
function isSeason(s: string): s is Season {
    return Object.keys(Seasons).includes(s)
}
```

What I cannot do, though, is get the compiler to check that all “season definitions” have a given type. If I define this:

```js
type SeasonData = typeof Seasons[Season]
```

then `SeasonData` is the union of the type of all definitions—no matter if they have the same shape or not.

So I'm looking for a syntactically non-redundant and light way to define something like:

```js
const Seasons: EnumWith<{temperature: number, startMonth: string}> = ... // as before
               ^^^^^^^^ <- to be defined!
```

Especially, I'm trying not to have to repeat the list of seasons in any other structure (interface or array) and to directly infer the type `Season` from the object definition (though hearing about alternative is always good!).

What could be done?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. When writing code, I begin with: `const Seasons: EnumWith<...> = {...}`. Once `Seasons` has a good shape, I remove the type and use `as const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your use case, the way I'd model the relationship between your types is something like the following

```js
type Season =
  | "winter"
  | "spring"
  | "summer"
  | "fall"

type Month =
  | "January"
  | "February"
  | "March"
  | "April"
  | "May"
  | "June"
  | "July"
  | "August"
  | "September"
  | "October"
  | "November"
  | "December"

type SeasonStruct = {
  temperature: number
  startMonth: Month
}

type Seasons = { [K in Season]: SeasonStruct }

const seasons: Seasons = {
    winter: { temperature: 5, startMonth: "December" },
    spring: { temperature: 20, startMonth: "March" },
    summer: { temperature: 30, startMonth: "June" },
    fall:   { temperature: 15, startMonth: "September" },
}
```

This should give you enough building blocks to represent everything you need in your domain, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks — works, but I have to maintain the list of seasons twice: once in the type and once in the definitions. No way to let the compiler infer it somehow?

Comment: Oh, and just learned that you can prefix a union type definition with `|` thanks to your example—very handy, looks nice!

Comment: `once in the type and once in the definitions` types only exist at compile time, and what you want is a runtime construct (the `seasons` object), so there is no way to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

Just found a somewhat convoluted way to extract the literal type information from the keys while still checking the values:

```js
function EnumWith<P>() {
    return function <K extends keyof any, R extends Record<K, P>>(defs: R): R {
        return defs
    }
}
```

which allows to write this:

```js
const Seasons = EnumWith<{
    temperature: number
    startMonth: Month // defined as in bugs's answer
}>()({
    winter: { temperature: 5, startMonth: "December" },
    spring: { temperature: 20, startMonth: "March" },
    summer: { temperature: 30, startMonth: "June" },
    fall: { temperature: 15, startMonth: "September" },
})
type Season = keyof typeof Seasons
```

The key was to find out that `K extends keyof any` lets you capture the type of the keys in a generic signature, and dividing the two generic types into two function calls so that we can specify one and let the other be inferred (currently not possible in a single function call in TypeScript).

So, granted, the line `}>()({` is a bit of an eyesore…

Comment: The problem is that TS currently does not allow inferring some type generic arguments while setting others ([Issue #26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)), otherwise you could just specify this to be a record of temperature & startMonth with inferred key.